# Visual Basic drawpolygon method using a do-while loop?

Tags: vb.net

I am looking for help with the drawpolygon method. I haven't had any luck getting anything to work. Looking to do 5 triangles, same size, next to each other. Problem is I have to use a do-while loop. Thanks for taking the time to help me!!

Comment: Did you get this resolved, Cliff?

Answer (score 2):

Just define the points in an array an then write them with a pen:

```
Dim blackPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 3)

Dim point1 As New Point(50, 50)
Dim point2 As New Point(100, 25)
Dim curvePoints As Point() = {point1, point2}

Me.CreateGraphics.DrawPolygon(blackPen, curvePoints)
```

Take a look at the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd0c4s09.aspx) about it.

It doesn't matter if you do anything in a loop, depends how. If this didn't solve your problem post your code in order to help you more.

Example with a loop:

```
Do While i < 3
    point1 As New Point(50 + i * 10, 50)
    point2 As New Point(100 + i * 7, 25)

    curvePoints = {point1, point2}
    Me.CreateGraphics.DrawPolygon(blackPen, curvePoints)
    i += 1
Loop
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get that code to work. I gave me errors. I really am lost on this. This works but not the bottom half of code you gave me. Any idea? I just draws 1 line then freezes. Looking for like 5 triangles         Dim i As Integer
        Dim blackPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 3)

        Do While i < 3
            Dim point1 As New Point(50, 50)
            Dim point2 As New Point(100, 25)
            Dim curvePoints As Point() = {point1, point2}

            Me.CreateGraphics.DrawPolygon(blackPen, curvePoints)
        Loop

Comment: @Cliff It freezes because its just an example and its an infinite loop... you have to modify the counter `i`. I edit my example, but you have to apply it to your own case.

Comment: I'm still confused. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me. If I copy both parts of your code, it gives me an error on the bottom half. point1, point2 and curvepoints all have an error when debugging. Getting things like Error 3 Method arguments must be enclosed in parentheses. Error 9 Expression is not a method.

Comment: @Cliff EDITED. But im just writing to you simplified advices and examples. You have to write your own code for your own situation. In any case, it should work now.

Comment: how to just draw like.. 1 triangle? And then I can take it from there

Comment: Just draw a polygon with the three points of a triangle, or draw manually the three lines xD

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tested this construction but it's all snipped out of a working project; I suspect it'll work and some of this GDI+ stuff is really grungy to pick up the first time.

```
Public Class Form1
Private subject As Image

Private Sub Form1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    If Not subject Is Nothing Then
        Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
        g.DrawImage(subject, New Point(1, 1))
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim tempBM As New Bitmap(subject)
    tempBM.SetResolution(subject.HorizontalResolution, subject.VerticalResolution)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(tempBM)
         g.DrawPolygon(OutlinePen, Polygon.GetPoints)
    End Using
    subject = tempBM
    Invalidate()
End Sub
End Class
```

Oh, Polygon is a class in my code that you won't have.  But just replace Polygon.GetPoints with whatever array of points you want to use.